# マテリアルアイコンはSVGで作成する際には何×何pixelが妥当ですか？

Tags: svg

WEBアプリに使用するマテリアルアイコンを作成したいのですが、以下リンク先のアイコンのSVGをみるとHTML用のインラインSVGが24×24pixelで作成されています。

[Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/)

> ```html
> <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
> ```

SVGなのになぜ24pixelで作成されているのか、もっと大きい or 小さいサイズ (100や10pixel等) で作成してはいけない理由があるのであれば教えていただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24 という数はマテリアルアイコンの作成ポリシーに則った結果と思われます。

> System icons are displayed as 24 x 24 dp. Create icons for viewing at 100% scale for pixel-perfect accuracy.

https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html#grid-and-keyline-shapes

Comment: ありがとうございます。